# Auto Complete minLength with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile-listview

Does anyone know how to add a minLength to a JqueryMobile auto complete?

The data is local and stored in a listview with data-filter-reveal set to true.

I see it can be done with JQuery UI, but can not find any documentation to do this with a local  data set in JQM.

Note: Working with Rails 3.

Thanks!